# How to determine if the current process is a Forms or a Console application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine the subsystem used by a given .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111669/how-can-i-determine-the-subsystem-used-by-a-given-net-assembly)

In my solution I have a generic error reporting library. In my programs in that solution I simply use it like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ErrorReporter.HandleUnhandledException;
```

Now I want to be able to react differently in `HandleUnhandledException` based on if it was called by a WinForms or a Console application.

Comment: This has already been asked: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111669/how-can-i-determine-the-subsystem-used-by-a-given-net-assembly  
and you can find the answer there.  
Also, you can use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() to get the assembly that started the process.

Comment: @Botz3000 Thanks, I guess I was using the wrong search terms.