# Using Invoke to run a hidden console application

Tags: c#, .net

From a C# program, I am executing a byte[] containing another .NET console-application directly in memory using the 'Invoke' method, with this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 byte[] Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test.exe");

 Assembly a = Assembly.Load(FileBytes);
 MethodInfo m = a.EntryPoint;
 var parameters = m.GetParameters().Length == 0 ? null : new[] { new string[0] };
 m.Invoke(null, parameters);
}
```

However, as the console-application that I am launching in memory ("C:\test.exe") never ends (it uses a while forever loop), the black cmd window never disappears.

How can it be executed hidden? As now I cannot use for example `'System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden'` as the process is not in disk.

Comment: you're launching, not lunching :) and see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden you could also see about just creating a Windows Service or starting this code from one, you wouldn't see the console window

Comment: @eddie_cat No lunch for me :(

Comment: lol sorry for my bad english =P

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `Process`?

Comment: Yes because using Process the console-application would have to be on disk, but I need it to be run directly on memory.

Comment: Can you change the console application's source code?

Comment: Yes, and it uses a forever while loop in main, so the cmd black window never disappears and could be annoying.

Comment: Yes it is I also developed it, it is a compiled C# console-application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1.Change your console application output type from `Console Application` to `Windows Application`. You can change it from `Project Properties`. This will hide the console window.

2.Write your assembly bytes to a file and use Process.Start to hide the console window. Something like this:

```
var f = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".exe";
File.WriteAllBytes(f, assemblyBytes);
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = f;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
p.Start();
```

Comment: As I can't touch disk I used your 1st solution and it worked. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's case they've clarified that they can modify the source of the assembly being loaded. In that case you should be able to just set the application to be a GUI application, which will prevent the console window from being opened.

See [How can I determine the subsystem used by a given .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111669/how-can-i-determine-the-subsystem-used-by-a-given-net-assembly) for a discussion of how to detect the application being console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this should work too, sadly I can only award 1 answer.